# Disabling autocomplete in comment blocks in Sublime Text

Tags: autocomplete, sublime-text-3

I have autocomplete activated with `"auto_complete_selector": "source"`, however when I'm writing long-form comment blocks the autocomplete suggestions are distracting (i.e. typing current attempts to autocomplete to [`current`](http://php.net/current)).

Can autocomplete be configured to only activate outside of a comment scope?

Answer (score 1):

Just set the following in your preferences:

```
"auto_complete_selector": "source -comment"
```

and you should be all set.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work inside comment blocks only usual comments ie `//`